# Unable to open camera , when clicked on camera icon ,toast message is displayed "Failed to create image file"

Tags: java, android

I am using https://github.com/esafirm/android-image-picker repository
For picking gallery image and capturing photo from camera.

But when I am clicking on Camera icon ,Toast message is shown **"Failed to create image file"**.

There is no other issue.

Code to call action I am using :

```
ImagePicker.create(EmployeeAttendanceDaily.this)
           .returnMode(ReturnMode.ALL) 
           .folderMode(true) // set folder mode (false by default)
           .single()
           .toolbarFolderTitle("Folder") // folder selection title
           .toolbarImageTitle("Tap to select")
           .toolbarDoneButtonText("DONE") // done button text
           .start(0);// image selection title
```

Device Details are :

- Android Version: 11
- Samsung S10

Is there a solution for this issue?

Comment: Where is the code that tries to create a file? In which storage location? Or code to start the camera? ImagePicker? You dont have to pick an image if you want to use the camera i think. But then i dont know that library. Please explain how it works.

Comment: You need to request manually the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission

Comment: @UsamaAltaf , i have requested a permission  WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE , but still issue persist.

Comment: @blackapps , its a library ,I can only call methods created.

Comment: You have the source code from github so you can see what happens and adapt the code.

Comment: "Is there a solution for this issue?" -- ask the developer of the library.

Comment: @CommonsWare , sure

Comment: Try these: `ImagePicker.cameraOnly().start(activity) // Could be Activity, Fragment, Support Fragment 

// You could also get the Intent 
ImagePicker.cameraOnly().getIntent(context)
`

Comment: Thanks @UsamaAltaf , issue was WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE ,Now I am able to capture image